# Вопрос закрыт - вопросы остались. Или еще о болдуинах

Tags: старая-орфография

[image: img]
(C)из поста grumant.

Помимо Болдуина, который Бодуэн, обращает на себя внимание две орфографические... гм... особенности. 
Ну Владимiр я еще могу понять, этимологию имени ошибочно производили от "Влади миром". А вот живого-то почему? "Живаго", однако... как и русскаго. Подделка? Или я опять чего-то путаю?

[image: http://eknigi.org/uploads/posts/2011-06/1309150631_1291401531_1286980818208.jpg]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Все правильно. Так и назывался словарь Даля. Правописание прилагательных соответствует написанию прилагательных в древнерусском языке. Полные прилагательные образовывались от кратких при помощи указательного местоимения,присоединявшегося к соответствующей падежной форме краткого прилагательного и склонявшегося. ТАк появились прилагательные типа живАГО (языка). Далее склонение прилагательных попало под влияние  форм указательных местоимений тъ, та, то. Появились прилагательные как в современном языке. -   живОГО.

Как писались прилагательные в первой пооловине 19 века?

•  В том случае, если прилагательное, местоимение, причастие или числительное в начальной форме оканчивалось на -ый, -ій (каждый, синій, бывшій, горькій, самый), то в родительном и винительном падежах мужского и среднего рода оно имело окончание -аго, -яго: каждаго, синяго, бывшаго, горькаго, самаго. Например: «яблоки самаго лучшаго сорта».

•  В противном случае писалось окончание -ого: земляной, этотъ, самъ — земляного, этого, самого. Например: «я видлъ недавно самого царя».

Получается, русскаго - написано в соответствии с орфографией того времени. А в слове живАго как бы ошибка. Как бы - потому что единой общепризнанной нормы дореформенной орфографии тогда  не существовало.

Answer (score 2):

Любопытно, что на обложке написано "живаго великору**с**каго языка", а не "живаго великору**сс**каго языка".

Comment: Спасибо. "На моей" картинке - новодел, ориентироваться на самом деле нельзя, но лишний раз говорит об уровне.)))

Comment: ![Даль](http://img18.slando.ua/images_slandocomua/87532807_1_1000x700_vladimir-dal-tolkovyy-slovar-zhivago-velikorusskago-yazyka-1881-god-faksimile-uzhgorod.jpg)
Даль применял очень своеобразную орфографию и очень не любил **удвоений**. Он писал : беславие, бесмертие, бесмыслие, определеный, исполненый, вобще, вображение, воружать, каса, маса, руский и тд. Разнобой в те времена был страшенный, как только школьники с этим справлялись!))))))) А Грот навел порядок, да. Сейчас его читаю и развлекаюсь тогдашними проблемами.

Comment: o! А сравнить два варианта? )))

Comment: Что ж там сравнивать? Надавал шелбанов швед Грот датчанину Далю да и упорядочил нам, сиволапым, русское правописание. Но за букву **ять** стоял крепко!

Comment: Ну кто там кому надавал - это к "Ментам", а насчет правописания... Получается, что одно и то же издание во втором томе использовало догротовкую орфографию, а в четвертом - уже писало по Гроту? Сомнительно.

А нет, это залепил. там вообще разные издания... Интересно, какой год у первого... Где Вы вообще картинки эти берете? там есть подробности?

Comment: @behemothus, Бодуэн-де-Куртене исправил и значительно дополнил словарь Даля (более 20 000 новых слов), изменение орфографии при таком раскладе не выглядит чем-то странным.[Предисловие Бодуэне-де-Куртене к 1-му выпуску](http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=251). ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/EbrNbGz.jpg

Comment: Знаю.
И как это связано с разговором?

Answer (score 2):

Я могу только сказать по поводу четырёх символов , которые  почему - то скопом , весьма некорректно называют вариантами звука "И".

Это не так. Первая русская письменность была глаголицей. Кирилл и Мефодий попросту её "переложили", иначе говоря, "перешрифтовали" - сейчас , например, эсэмэски дешевле посылать на латинице, чем на кириллице.

Ростислав не просил создавать письменность. Он просил учителей, которые  бы  защитили ег граждан от влияния немцев, греков и влахов. Влахи - это как раз те, кто в своё время выпер  ильменских славян с Иллирии (в книге , на карте С.У. Ремезова новгородцы помечены именно как илллирийские словены и Великая скифь).

Волохи - это и есть то, что называлось раньше русью. Это была сеть работорговцев, действовавшая по всей Восточной Европе - Западная Европа была вотчиной евреев - рахдонитов. Если кто знает - вся миссия  из нескольких десятков болгарских попов, кроме Кирилла и Мефодия,  была выловлена и продана в рабство в г. Венеция.

Глаголица - это не просто азбука и письменность. Это ещё и система счёта, поскольку каждая цифра в то время обозначалась буквой. Так вот, если сравнить числовые значения глаголиц и кириллицы, то они совпадают только в ТРЁХ случаях. 
Вы теперь представьте, каким образом можно было соблюдать священный день пасхи, если он высчитываается по числовым значениям букв. Стало быть, высчитывая в глаголическом исчислении, вы получите разницу, высчитывая в кириллице.

Что касается знаков , обозначавших якобы звук "и", об этом подробно в "Открытом письме доктору филологических наук Карпенко Л.Б.":

Иван Александрович Стрельцов.

http://proza.ru/avtor/vanostrel

https://sites.google.com/site/istoriabezskazok/Home/glagoli

Comment: >Я могу только сказать по поводу четырёх символов , которые почему - то скопом , весьма некорректно называют вариантами звука "И".   
  
**Символы** не называют вариантами **звука**. Дальнейшее обсуждать бессмыслено.